# Beam/Dataflow: Understanding why batch job stop before Stateful Pardo step

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I have a pipeline that essentially reads in compressed JSON data, does a little processing and writes it out via a bulk API request. It accomplish the bulk API request, I have a DoFn that buffers a certain amount of data (say 1500 records) and flushes the batch when it hits that threshold ([pretty much exactly how it does it in the Beam Blog post](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/08/28/timely-processing.html))

The way the pipeline executes in Dataflow is it reads in ALL of the JSON data (almost 1 TB worth) before going into the batch step. Any idea what is going on here? The intermediate step "Add Random Key" essentially takes in a JSON string and outputs a KV of `(random.nextInt(), jsonString)`, which was added to prevent fusion to the batch + API call section

[image]

Edit: Adding a code snippet for the "Buffer" section:

```
new DoFn<KV<String, String>, KV<String, String>>() {

  private static final int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 500;
  private static final Duration MAX_BUFFER_DURATION = Duration.standardSeconds(1);

  @TimerId("stale")
  private final TimerSpec staleSpec = TimerSpecs.timer(TimeDomain.PROCESSING_TIME);

  @StateId("buffer")
  private final StateSpec<BagState<String>> bufferedEvents = StateSpecs.bag();

  @StateId("count")
  private final StateSpec<ValueState<Integer>> countState = StateSpecs.value();

  @ProcessElement
  public void process(
      ProcessContext context,
      @StateId("buffer") BagState<KV<String, String>> bufferState,
      @TimerId("stale") Timer staleTimer,
      @StateId("count") ValueState<Integer> countState) {
    if (firstNonNull(countState.read(), 0) == 0) {
      staleTimer.offset(MAX_BUFFER_DURATION).setRelative();
    }
    int count = firstNonNull(countState.read(), 0);
    count = count + 1;
    countState.write(count);
    bufferState.add(context.element().value());

    if (count >= MAX_BUFFER_SIZE) {
      for (KV<String, String> enrichedEvent : enrichEvents(bufferState.read())) {
        context.output(KV.of(RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(1), enrichedEvent));
      }
      bufferState.clear();
      countState.clear();
    }
  }



  @OnTimer("stale")
  public void onStale(
      OnTimerContext context,
      @StateId("buffer") BagState<Event> bufferState,
      @StateId("count") ValueState<Integer> countState) {
    if (!bufferState.isEmpty().read()) {
      for (String enrichedEvent : enrichEvents(bufferState.read())) {
        context.output(KV.of(RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(1), enrichedEvent));
      }
      bufferState.clear();
      countState.clear();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be good if you can add the code snippet for the ParDo named "Buffer".

Comment: Just added a code snippet above for Buffer

Comment: The code looks correct, couple of things to look for is if the Window and triggering is setup correctly. If it is can you put a log to print the value of count to see if there are any issues in that.

Comment: Do you get some error message? What exactly happens?

Comment: No error message, it loads all the data to persistent disk and once all the data is loaded in it continues

Comment: Will not the job be completed if you wait? I mean, what makes you think its stuck and not only slow since you're using a big file as input?

Comment: Assuming this to be a batch pipeline. For Batch, this is an expected behavior. Batch pipelines handles triggers and timers differently as emitting continuous early results are not meaningful in batch context. It is expected to process individual steps completely before moving to next step in the pipeline. This also delays firing of triggers and timers as they will be processed once all the data from previous step is processed. However, state backed buffering will still be honored with delay based on completion of previous step.